# Getting server's CPU usage percentage VBScript

Tags: vbscript, cpu

How to get CPU Usage percentage using VBScript?

I got a piece of code but I don't think I am getting the result that I am looking for.

See screenshot below for the *percentage* that I am referring:

[image]

Comment: "I got a piece of code but I don't think I am getting the result that I am looking for." - What is your code?

Answer (score -1):

I hope this code will help you

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\localhost\root\CIMV2") 
Set CPUInfo = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor",,48) 
For Each Item in CPUInfo 
    Wscript.Echo "PercentProcessorTime: " & Item.PercentProcessorTime
Next
```